# How do I reinstall a directory in /usr/bin/python

Tags: python, directory, installation, bin

I have researched this for hours to no avail.

I think I deleted my directory at /usr/bin/python when I installed python 3 because I get this error: `-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory.`

I've tried `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`, and that gives me `ln: /usr/bin/python: File exists`

However, it still doesn't permanently install a directory in /usr/bin/python. How do I permanently restore this directory?

I'm on a mac.

Thanks!

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` should be a file, not a directory. What does running `ls -l /usr/bin/python` output?

Comment: You've probably deleted a library used by python, not python itself.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your file /usr/bin/python exists because you get the message:

```
ln: /usr/bin/python: File exists
```

but I see that it is a corrupted link to something that doesn't exist, because you get the message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

What you have to do to fix that is:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python    # because that's a corrupted file
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python    # this line will work if your file /usr/bin/python2.7 is OK.
```

Hope that helps!